# Data too big for QR Code Generation with XZing in Android with Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, qr-code

I am trying to generate a QR Code and set it to an ImageView out of a PGP Public Key in my Android Application with Java. The libary I use is XZing and I am on Android Studio.
This worked well before with smaller Strings, however when I try to do it with something as big as a PGP Public Key I get this error:

```
    com.google.zxing.WriterException: Data too big
```

So my data is too big. Is there any possibility to create a QR Code with a String this big in XZing?

I have tried it with two different methods but both lead to the same exception.

**Method one:**

```
    private void generateQR(String value) {
        qrImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

      QRGEncoder qrgEncoder = new QRGEncoder(value, null, QRGContents.Type.TEXT, 1000);

        try {
            // Getting QR-Code as Bitmap
            Bitmap bm = qrgEncoder.encodeAsBitmap();

                qrImage.setImageBitmap(bm);

            // Setting Bitmap to ImageView
        } catch (WriterException e) {
            Log.v(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
```

**Method two:**

```
private Bitmap textToImage(String text, int width, int height) throws WriterException, NullPointerException {
        BitMatrix bitMatrix;
        try {
            bitMatrix = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(text, BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX.QR_CODE,
                    width, height, null);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException Illegalargumentexception) {
            return null;
        }

        int bitMatrixWidth = bitMatrix.getWidth();
        int bitMatrixHeight = bitMatrix.getHeight();
        int[] pixels = new int[bitMatrixWidth * bitMatrixHeight];

        int colorWhite = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        int colorBlack = 0xFF000000;

        for (int y = 0; y < bitMatrixHeight; y++) {
            int offset = y * bitMatrixWidth;
            for (int x = 0; x < bitMatrixWidth; x++) {
                pixels[offset + x] = bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? colorBlack : colorWhite;
            }
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitMatrixWidth, bitMatrixHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

        bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, bitMatrixWidth, bitMatrixHeight);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

QR Codes have a max size.
I changed the error correction level to `L` and this then can fit in a longer URL.

This may work for you:

```
new MultiFormatWriter().encode(qrCodeText, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height, mapWith(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L));
```

Comment: What library is `mapWith(...)` from?

Comment: I figured out that it just doesn't make sense to have a QR-Code with this much information, since the QR-Image will be unreadable and you won't be able to scan it. So this limit makes sense.

Comment: @AztecCodes did you find the solution for this issue? if yes please suggest.I too have the same issue in qr code generation. thanks

Comment: @mobi_dev The framework itself sets a limit of text length, because the QR-Code won't be scannable anyways with that much information.